# SlideDateTimePicker Datetime picker open issue

Tags: android

integrated this library [SlideDateTimePicker](https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker)

Code

```
 new SlideDateTimePicker.Builder(getSupportFragmentManager())
                .setListener(listener)
                .setInitialDate(new Date())
                .build()
                .show();
```

Error

Log 1

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DateFragment{8cb3765 #0 id=0x7f12026c android:switcher:2131886700:0} declared target fragment 
 that does not belong to this FragmentManager
```

Log 2

```
                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id 2131886700: com.github.jjobes.slidedatetimepicker.CustomViewPager#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18800)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: error says setMeasuredDimension() is missing. may be you forgot to add that in your code

Comment: error from library code CustomViewPager

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in Library code able to change 2 classes  1. `TimeFragment`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
            mCallback = (TimeChangedListener) getParentFragment();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Calling fragment must implement " + "TimeFragment.TimeChangedListener interface");
    }
}
```

2.`Change following code in DateChangedListener`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        mCallback = (DateChangedListener) getParentFragment();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Calling fragment must implement " + "DateFragment.DateChangedListener interface");
    }
}
```

3.`SlideDateTimeDialogFragment`

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            DateFragment dateFragment = DateFragment.newInstance(
            mTheme,
            mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            mMinDate,
            mMaxDate);
            //  dateFragment.setTargetFragment(SlideDateTimeDialogFragment.this, 100);
            return dateFragment;
       case 1:
            TimeFragment timeFragment = TimeFragment.newInstance(
            mTheme,
            mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            mIsClientSpecified24HourTime,
            mIs24HourTime);
            // timeFragment.setTargetFragment(SlideDateTimeDialogFragment.this, 200);
            return timeFragment;
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

Here due to set `setTargetFragment` not able to load Fragment, need to comment and change `getTargetFragment();` to `getParentFragment()`

```
// timeFragment.setTargetFragment(SlideDateTimeDialogFragment.this, 200);
```

Comment: @ankitukumar after adding ur code in libraries it give me null exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.github.jjobes.slidedatetimepicker.DateFragment$DateChangedListener.onDateChanged(int, int, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: please help about this issue

Comment: thanks it worked for me but do you have a explanation? because it was working fine and somehow it started to have a pb then your solution resolve it @Ankitkumar Makwana

Comment: IT WORKS !!! thank U man . I think u miss typed the 2nd filename "DateChangedListener"  It will be "DateFragment"

Comment: now work.. thank you,..
yaa, the 2nd filename "DateChangedListener" It will be not. this name is "DayFragment.java", change in that class.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Ankitkumar Makwana but it not all, also need change in class **SlideDateTimeDialogFragment** in method **initViewPager**

```
getFragmentManager()
```

replace to

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```